# Перевод строки времени в удобный формат PHP

Tags: php

Есть строка со временем:

```
1565081592089
```

Как корректно перевести её в другой формат "час:минута:секунда день.месяц.год"? Делаю так:

```
$time = '1565081592089';
echo date('H:i:s d.m.Y', $time);
```

Получаю неверный результат:

```
22:41:29 17.06.51565
```

Где ошибка? Формат времени мне не известен, так как он генерируется системой комментирования Cackle. Но Яндекс преобразует его верно. Вот:

```
вторник, 6 августа 2019 г. 11:53:12.089 (MSK)
```

Comment: В каком формате ваша строка со временем? И какой результат вы ожидаете?

Comment: Проблема в том, что я не знаю. Эта строка выдаётся системой комментирования Cackle.

Comment: Но Яндекс переводит верно.

Comment: в метод date надо передавать timestamp, а ваша строка это не timestamp. Надо узнать что за формат

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть подозрение, что последние 3 цифры в вашей метке времени — это миллисекунды. Попробуйте их обрезать и уже потом подставить в функцию `date()`:

```php
$time = substr(1565081592089, 0, -3);
echo date('H:i:s d.m.Y', $time);
```

Comment: Да, точно... Спасибо!